# How does this inline assembly define a variable?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

In the linux kernel you find assembly as follows:

```
#define DEFINE(sym, val) \
        asm volatile("\n->" #sym " %0 " #val : : "i" (val))
```

which when used like this

```
DEFINE(NR_PAGEFLAGS, __NR_PAGEFLAGS);
```

generates the following assembly

```
->NR_PAGEFLAGS $24 __NR_PAGEFLAGS
```

which apparently is valid assembly. What does this do?

How does this asm define a variable? Please point me to any documentation which explains this in more detail. Thanks!

Comment: The colons are confusing, and I'm curious too, but I _think_ if sym and val are strings, that first part will catenate them. In C if you have two string literals next to each other they're catenated by the compiler and treated as one literal, so that whole first part, `"\n->" #sym " %0 " #val` would just boil down to one string. Although that'd depend on how this was used, and I generally stay away from precompiler functions so I dunno.

Comment: added the generated assembly for clarity.

Comment: apparently it has something to do with generated Kbuild headers and not assembly per se

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not valid assembly. It gets transformed using a sed script into something like:

```
#define NR_PAGEFLAGS 24
```

This file is then included by many assembly source files, this allows the results of C constant expressions used in assembler files.

Comment: Could you please point to the sed script which transforms this? Thanks!

Comment: It is in Kbuild in the top level kernel source directory.